# Pull distinct value to show oldest date and nested with certain criteria SQL

Tags: sql

```
 Item  dateordered       codeordered
    A     3/5/12         old
    A     1/1/14         regular
    A     2/1/13         notregular
    B     4/5/13         regular
```

I’d like to create a syntax that pulls distinct for :

Oldest date items got ordered (A and B), which has the codeordered in (regular or old) only.

So my desired result is:

```
Item A, dateordered 3/5/12
Item B, dateordered 4/5/13
```

I tried to create temporary table, and pulled mindistinct for dateordered from it, but for item A it still pulls both days of 3/5/12 and 1/1/14.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for this:

```
SELECT 
    Item,
    MIN(DateOrdered) EarliestOrderDate
FROM the_table
WHERE CodeOrdered IN ('Regular', 'Old')
GROUP BY Item
```